# High performance file IO in Android

Tags: java, android, file-io, randomaccessfile, mappedbytebuffer

I'm creating an app which communicates with an ECG monitor. Data is read at a rate of 250 samples pr second. Each package from the ECG monitor contains 80 bytes and this is received 40 times per second.

I've tried using a RandomAcccessFile but packages were lost both in sync
`RandomAccessFile(outputFile, "rws")` and async  `RandomAccessFile(outputFile, "rw")` mode.

In a recent experiment I've tried using the MappedByteBuffer. This should be extremely performant, but when I create the buffer I have to specify a size `map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 10485760)` for a 10MB buffer. But this results in a file that's always 10MB in size. Is it possible to use a MappedByteBuffer where the file size is only the actual amount of data stored?

Or is there another way to achieve this? Is it naive to write to a file this often?

On a side note this wasn't an issue at all on iOS - this can be achieved with no buffering at all.

Comment: How are you receiving the data? What device are you writing to? Have you determined if it's reading or writing that's too slow?

Comment: `Is it naive to write to a file this often?`. Sorry, but you did not tell how often you write to that file.